# What is wrong with this rot13 cipher?

Tags: go

I'm having some trouble with tour.golang.org/methods/23

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (r rot13Reader) Read(s []byte) (int, error) {
    a, e := r.r.Read(s)
    for i := 0; i < a; i++ {
        if(s[i] >= 'a') {
            s[i] = ((s[i] - 'a') + 13) % 26 + 'a'   
        }
        if(s[i] >= 'A') {
            s[i] = ((s[i] - 'A') + 13) % 26 + 'A'   
        }
    }
    return a, e
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

I'm adding then modding but the results don't quite look right after accounting for the gap between the ascii codes for lower and upper case

`YHN VKTVDXW MAX VHWX!`

Comment: The problem with (a + 13) % 26 is that the letters `a` through `z` do not have the values 0 through 25.

Comment: I think you want to only rotate a character if it already is a letter. Also, remember that  Go strings are UTF-8 by default.  See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for and https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8

Comment: @duckbrain Does utf8 have a different ordering to byte sized characters than ascii? I'm using this table as a guide https://www.easycalculation.com/unit-conversion/alphabets-ascii-code.php

Comment: No, but the code makes changes to all characters `>= 'a'`, which does include characters higher than Ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'A'` is (numerically speaking) 65.  Letters deeper in the alphabet increase, up to `'Z'` which is 90.

`'a'` is (numerically speaking) 97.  Letters deeper in the alphabet increase, up to `'z'` which is 122.

(Don't ask why I have some ASCII memorized. I did have to look up the `z` values. :-) )

Exercise 1: if `s[i]` is `'a'`, i.e., 97, and you rot-13 it to `'n'` (110), is this greater than 65?  What happens when you get to your *second* `if` statement?

Exercise 2: if `s[i]` is `'_'` (decimal 95), what happens here?

(You keep changing your question, so by now these exercises are somewhat moot.)

Comment: Sorry about changing the question. I'm not sure how to express partial improvements to the question that I found bringing me closer to the solution. I'll upvote your answer and accept it.

Comment: Generally, you can edit the question to add things you've realized, but StackOverflow is kind of the wrong place for this sort of interactive stuff. There's a code-review StackExchange site as well (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but that's more for "it works, is there a better way"...

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the ascii values of the letters directly, you have to offset them. The ascii values of capital A-Z are 65-90 inclusive, and lowercase a-z are 97-122 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to only do letters by fixing the bounds on letter checking

between 'a' and 'z' and between 'A' and 'Z'

your second Z was lowercase when it needs to be uppercase

Comment: If you are answering your own question why are you referring to " ... *your* second Z was lowercase ..."

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum I was trying to make the question and answer sound more similar to most answers with the questioner and the answerer being 2 individuals.